# Formula to Calculate a Total Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I need to input a $ amount, and need to calculate the monthly amount based on whatever is input. The amounts being calculated are weekly, monthly, bi-annually, and yearly and would each need their own calculation to come up with a monthly amount (the monthly amount would remain the same as input).

The fixed expense $ amount is entered in column D with the dropdown options in Column E, and final total in Column F of one sheet and the dropdown list/table (weekly, monthly, bi-annually, yearly) are on another sheet in column O. I have the dropdown working and I know how to write a formula to add a range of cells on different sheets, but I am stuck at how to write a formula that runs a calculation based on the option selected from the dropdown list.

At this moment, this is the code that I have:

```
=SUM('Audit'!O20:P23) * VLOOKUP(E5, 'Parameters'!O20:P23, 2)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfvJd.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A10Or.png]

Comment: Your pictures are meaningless because we can't tell which cells/worksheets they represent nor what they correspond to in your explanation. Even if you don't have a formula, show where you start from and what you want the output to look like by manually doing. Maybe we can then figure out a way to turn it into a formula. Your explanation is somewhat hard to follow.

Comment: The #VALUE! is the formula result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't look up a mathematical expression that includes the operator like that.

Presuming your current value for 'Bi-Annual' is correct as-is (wondering if it should be `/2`), put these in the amount column:

```
4
1
=1/3
=1/12
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

These multipliers can then be grabbed by your VLOOKUP and applied to the rest of the calculation.

Comment: ,, is nice one ,, please add a sample `Vlookup` command also,,, will help the OP & others also ,,,, +10 ☺

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include the VLOOKUP because it's in OP's question and I think it doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I’ll fix. It was a late night of frustration. As for the rest of your comment, changing the mathematical expression is what worked, and the sheet now works. THANK YOU!!